# SCSS + Vue Components

Tags: sass, vue.js

I am using `<style lang="scss">` inside my single file Vue components. But in every single component using my color variables, I need to import the file, ie: `@import "./../../../sass/variables";`. I am using Laravel Mix to compile the sass + js.

Is there any way to make the varaible accessible without needing to import them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this related issue on github, I think it has the right answer for you:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328

Specially look for mister **shaun-sweet**'s answer.